# View not retrieving any data and losing connection with database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a new view on my database but for some reason everytime I try to do so the view itself doesn't return any data and make me lose connection to the server.
The interesting part is that if I run my entire query at the directly on the server without a view it return all the rows without a problem.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT C.*,
(CASE
    WHEN C.TEC = 'Ind'
        THEN (select distinct I."FINAL" from IND I WHERE I.GUIDE = C.GUIDE AND ROWNUM = 1)
        ELSE (select distinct Z."FINAL" from NEST Z WHERE Z.TYPE = C.TYPE AND ROWNUM = 1)
    END) FINAL_POINT,
(CASE
    WHEN C.TEC = 'Ind'
        THEN (select count(distinct I."FINAL") from IND I WHERE I.GUIDE = C.GUIDE)
        ELSE (select count(distinct Z."FINAL") from NEST Z WHERE Z.TYPE = C.TYPE)
    END) COUNT_FINAL_POINT  

FROM
(SELECT A.*,(select TYPE from AUX B where A.REF = B.REF AND A.TEC != 'Ind') TYPE
FROM NCL A) C
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Drop the view and recreate - does it still give you same issues?

Comment: Yeap, still same thing.

Comment: What is the view and what is the query?

Comment: How many columns returned by c.* ? I read somewhere that maximum columns could be 1000, which is highly unlikely, but still gotta ask.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The Query I added to the question it the on I'm trying to create a view with.

Comment: @Utsav It only has 20 something columns and 17k rows

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso - Gordon meant the query you are using to create view starting from `create or replace view ....` till the end.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith sorry about the newb question but where can i find that?

Comment: @Utsav I'm just right clicking on Views folder, Create New on Connections tab of Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: sql developer has an alert log report you can try, reports > database admin > alert log. you can also check the diagnostic dest parameter for your db - it will be set to a directory on your db server

Comment: you can also just query X$dbgalertext as SYS

Comment: I'm not being able to find it. Maybe I don't have permission to access it?
When I try to run X$dbgalertext it says: Error report: Unkown Command

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I just found it but it doens't show any kind of error. I think it is just not executing the view for some reason

Comment: normally if your connection is dying, it might be due to an ORA-600, and you'd want to look for those around the time of your query running/not-running

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso is the following statement in your query `SELECT A.*,(select TYPE from AUX B where A.REF = B.REF AND A.TEC != 'Ind') TYPE
FROM NCL A` valid